# Migrate SharePoint form 2007 to 2013

Tags: migration

I am planning to Upgrade my moss 2007 Environment to SharePoint 2013 Environment.

can anyone suggest me what are the best practices for doing this.

Like: 
Best suited environment.
Solution architecture.
Steps to perform..

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Praveen Singh

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't upgrade Moss 2007 to SharePoint 2013, you will need to upgrade it to SharePoint 2010 and then to SharePoint 2013.

Your question is too broad to answer here, so I will give you links you should look at,

[Upgrade and migration for SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214.aspx)

[Proven Practices for Migrating to SharePoint 2013](http://www.docpointsolutions.com/documents/Share-Point-2013-Migration-White-Paper.pdf)

https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Can-I-upgrade-from-MOSS-2816293.S.174267533